# How to format org table field while keeping numeric value for other formulas?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Say I create a table like this:

```
|  Number | Share price |    Total |
|---------+-------------+----------|
|     500 |        6.90 | $3450.00 |
```

And that 3rd field is calculated. If I use the formula `$1*$2` it works and displays `3450.`. If I want to format it more like a currency, with a "$" sign, I can use Lisp and make the formula: `'(format "$%.2f" (* $1 $2));N`. That gives the result as shown in the table above, but it breaks other formulas that were using that "Total" field and expecting a number.

I'm trying to replace an Apple Numbers spreadsheet. The typical thing there is to set the cell's "format" to "currency". It displays a dollar sign but doesn't change the underlying value as used by other formulas.

Is there a way to do that with Org tables? In other words, is there a way to format a cell while keeping its numeric value for easy use in other formulas?

Comment: It's too low-level to be called a solution, but you can use overlays to change the appearance of things, while the underlying buffer remains unchanged (that's how e.g links are formatted), but that would be the first step in a real solution. Being able to declare a column as "currency" and having Org mode apply the appropriate overlay would be the next step, but AFAIK, neither step is available currently.

Comment: You could perhaps use Lisp to parse that string and discard the currency character.

Comment: @aadcg: the trouble with that is that you have to change *every* formula that uses that field (or column).

Comment: Thanks @NickD, I'll look into overlays. I'm really liking org mode right now, imperfect beast that it is. I wonder if they'd accept a patch for a feature like that if I got deeply enough into to it to implement it well. That and I also want cells with row and column spans, and I want unicode to not screw up the cell widths... but I digress.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Feel free to join the mailing list and discuss it. See https://orgmode.org for details, and check out the [How to contribute](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contribute.html) link.